# Magento: Export Main Navigation HTML via Cronjob for Typo3

Tags: php, html, magento, cron, typo3

**We have the following setup**

- Typo3 for all CMS pages (also the home)
- The Magento Shop is running under a subfolder (let's say http://www.our-cms-and-shop.com/magento)
- Both systems exchange data asynchronously via HTML snippet exports (in both directions)
- The Magento shop has a highly customized main navigation menu. The following blocks plus templates have been customized in a custom theme:

  ```
  <block type="core/text_list" name="top.menu" as="topMenu" translate="label">
      <label>Navigation Bar</label>
      <block type="page/html_topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="page/html/topmenu.phtml"/>
      <block type="page/html_topmenu_renderer" name="catalog.topnav.renderer" template="page/html/topmenu/renderer.phtml"/>
  </block>
  ```
- The customized main navigation also contains catalog products

**What we want to do**

- The main navigation must look identically on all Typo3 and Magento pages
- Typo3 should get a ready-to-use HTML snippet. We want to use exactly the output of Magento's `top.menu` block. E.g. in a non-customized Magento shop it should contain the whole `header-nav` element:

  ```
  <div class="skip-content" id="header-nav">
      <nav id="nav">
          <ol class="nav-primary">
              .........
          </ol>
      </nav>
  </div>
  ```
- We want ot export the whole contents of the `top.menu` block defined in the main layout `page.xml`
- We export the HTML in a fixed cycle with a cronjob (e.g. every 15 minutes). So we don't have to observe the events of category and product changes. This could cause a non-synchronized navigation menus in Typo3 and Magento, but that's ok for the time of the cron cycle

What can be possible solutions for this task?

In Magento's cronjob scope the frontend layouts are not initialized, so we can't use it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new extension, which provides a fluid view helper, that includes content from an external source. You just need to get the html sourcecode from the magento instance using curl and cut out the navigation part.
To speed things up, save the extracted content in a file in the typo3temp directory. If the specified file is present, it will return its content, else it fetches the content from magento.

Then you can create a TYPO3 scheduler command task, which deletes the file in the typo3temp-directory every 15 minutes. That will force the view helper to get fresh contents.

Comment: My question was how to implement this in Magento and not the Typo3 integration. Anyways thank you for your answer.